# Problem running DELETE statement against linked server in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I'm having a problem running this query:

```
DELETE FROM [IRPROD]..[BUDGET_USER].[GL_EXP]
WHERE FISCAL_YEAR = 2010
```

IRPROD is a linked server to an Oracle 10g database. It's linked using the Oracle OleDB provider. There are ~79000 records that need to be deleted. Running this query it deletes 54. Running it again gives me this error message.

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "IRPROD" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "IRPROD".
```

Obviously, "catastrophic failure" is something bad. But the weird thing is that I can run SELECT and INSERT statements all day and it works fine. I do have permissions to delete the rows. Also, if I link the table through Access I can delete the records.

Any ideas?

Comment: Suggestion to help diagnostic: Try adding a condition in the where clause for example WHERE FISCAL_YEAR = 2010 AND some_other_column < some_value giving a very few row.   The idea is to determine if the error is tied to deleting one particular row or just any row.

Comment: Good idea. I ran another query which would have deleted 8 rows but it came back and said "0 rows affected". Funny thing is that it takes the same amount of time for it to come back with a result (1:15). Now there are no indexes or keys on this table. Could that affect it?

Comment: @Clint  That's odd indeed (0 rows affected rather than 8). I'm assuming you checked that the 8 rows were effectively _not_ deleted.  On the constant duration of the query that is normal/expected: with no indexes the selection of the rows to delete implies a table scan of sorts, which, if the table is sizeable would take a relatively long time and would take more or less the same amount (difference only because of some caching etc.).  I'm assuming the select query used for checking rows, diagnostics etc. is same as one show, but for `DELETE` replaced by `SELECT *`

Comment: Indeed no rows were deleted. It is strange and it seems there is not much documentation on linked servers when things go wrong.

Comment: I have the timeout set to 0 (infinite) on the sql server side. There could be a timeout on the oracle side but this is only running 1:30 max and we have other queries that run much longer than that that work fine.

I did add a unique index and now it will delete 191 rows but still not all of them. Also, OPENQUERY doesn't work at all. It says I don't have permissions, which I do. I'm wondering if this is a driver issue?

Comment: if you change the DELETE to a SELECT, will it return all of the rows you want to delete?

Comment: Yes it will. 

This makes the comment more than 15 characters.

Comment: are there any constraints that cause the delete to fail?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but I'll check.

Comment: Ok, there were no constriants. But I did find a tidbit of information in some MS documentation that said that the tables being linked to could not have nullable fields. So when I changed all the fields to not null it works. Now the problem is that it is very slow.

Comment: "So when I changed all the fields to not null it works. Now the problem is that it is very slow."  That sounds like a solution for this question, and the seed for a new one.

Comment: It is, I just want to duplicate the results before I finalize the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this turned out to be an easy fix with a complicated explanation.

First problem was an outdated Oracle driver. We were using the version 9 provider so I updated to the 10g provider provided through our OIT shop. Turns out the one they have has a bug in it. So I uninstalled it and installed the 10g provider from Oracle which is updated to fix the bug.

Second, I changed the 'fiscal_year' field from varchar2 type to a number type. If you send a DELETE statement with a WHERE (or maybe any conditional clause, I only checked WHERE)  that compares against a test field, then SQL Server must do a remote scan on the table, which basically retrieves the data and has to one-by-one delete each row. If you send a DELETE statement with a WHERE that is numeric, then SQL Server can pass on the query directly to the remote DB without doing a remote scan.

I hope this helps somebody. I found this by trial and error and bit's and pieces from the internet. Thanks for all that helped on this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is OleDB provider and Database Bug 5043675:
Setting up a linked server works fine to read data but updating or deleting data fails with the error.

Use Patches 5043675, 6637236

You can download them from Oracle Support.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it was part of the problem. Also, it is helpful to provide links in your answers, it makes it much easier for the end reader.